# Buck converter extreme voltage drop?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck

I am trying to power a Raspberry Pi from a 12v power source in a car. I have tried half a dozen different step-down boards and they all behave the same way, which I don't understand. From a bench power supply set at 12v, the system works perfectly. It produces 5.08v and when I hook it to the Pi it maybe drops .01v, the Pi boots up, everything is great.

When I hook this same hardware to a 12v source in the car, some of the regulators will immediately drop to 1.8-2v in no-load conditions, and all of them definitely drop to that range under load. I've been doing this purely off the car battery at the moment, so isn't any fluctuation in the system voltage.

I'm not sure even what to search for to describe this condition but my understanding of how these step-down circuits work is limited. Clearly this is a thing that is possible because there are 12v USB chargers and those work just fine in this car. The 12v source I am using would normally power the CD changer, and I have metered it at 12v +- 1%.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried half a dozen different step-down boards" - exactly which ones were they? "When I hook this same hardware to a 12v source in the car..." - _which_ 12V source in the car, and how did you connect them to it? "I have metered it at 12v +- 1%" - was that 12V +- 1% measured at the input to the regulator when loaded? (a car battery normally puts out significantly more than 12V).

Comment: We need some details please. Diagrams, schematic if possible, or at least a layout diagram. Show what fails and what works.

Comment: Car battery isn't an ideal 12V. If the buck converter you are using drops out at <12V or shuts down for safety at voltages >12V, it's not going to be appropriate. Tell us the part you are using, I'm curious.

Comment: Your experiment was performed as accurately as it sounds without accurate measurements of voltage and test load currents. Can the source light a bulb? Does your PS draw more than a bulb on startup? How do tell without instruments Put the bulb in series.

Comment: Why all this trouble if you just can use an off-the-shelf car USB charger? It doesn't drop to anything, just +5V.

Comment: All questions starting with I am trying , indicate a wish to know yet a lack of experience on how to perform experiments with specs or many measurable parameters that give clues.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Here is an example of a component that I tested today: [https://www.amazon.com/Pololu-Step-Down-Voltage-Regulator-D24V50F5/dp/B01M659ER2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1521691379&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=pololu+5v%2C+5a+step-down+voltage+regulator+d24v50f5&psc=1]

Comment: @AliChen mainly because this won't end up being located near a 12v accessory outlet so I'd be hacking one of them up for the guts anyway.

Comment: @STWilliams https://www.amazon.com/Pololu-Step-Down-Voltage-Regulator-D24V50F5/dp/B01M659ER2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1521691379&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=pololu+5v%2C+5a+step-down+voltage+regulator+d24v50f5&psc=1

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yep, will light a bulb. The circuit in the car is fused at 7.5A, and it seems to me that if I'm stepping 12v down to 5v at 2.5A max (what the converter is rated for) then counting for inefficiency I should be drawing under 2A off the source. I'm a software engineer by trade, I know just enough about EE to be dangerous.

Comment: Then maybe you should state your question with drawing schematically you connection diagram(s), both for your CD power supply, and for a car. It is really difficult to mess up two wires.

Comment: The statement "if I'm stepping 12v down to 5v at 2.5A max" doesn't make much sense. Please describe more accurately, algorithmically, what are you doing.

Comment: It seems if you can measure the input and output , you could show a photo of the unit , or better links to datasheet and intermediate test points near input to debug it.  Did you notice the Enable Input?

Comment: Is the car battery working? Test it under load to see if the voltage drops

Comment: @A.S., shouldn't it be assumed that OP is dealing with a running car? But your comment is pretty good :-)

Comment: @jimbojsb - I recommend that you edit your question and add clear photos of one of the buck regulators *and* the added wiring when installed in the car, and when you've confirmed that the exact setup in the photos has the problem, by measuring the input *and* output voltages (even better if you can include the DMM display showing input and output voltages in your photos). I suggest that one of the buck regulators you mentioned, whose output drops to "1.8-2v in no-load conditions" would be a good candidate for the photos. No need to add the RPi to show the problem in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading a 12V->5V step-down converter with a 2 A load (fully loaded/running PRi3, or 2.5 Ohm resistor), you should expect the input current to the convertor (on 12-V side) to be about 1 A (assuming 80% efficiency).

A correctly wired car cigarette lighter outlet can deliver 10 to 20 A of current at battery level (~12 - ~13 V). So loading a lighter outlet with 1 A should result in no visible drop in voltage.

If you are using some non-standard hook-up to car battery network, and experience horrible voltage drop, it only means that you somehow got the power incorrectly. Check your car schematics for right wires to hook.

Comment: And I hope you are not using AWG30 magnet wire for your 12-V side of power.